# What are some tricks to perform integer division quickly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

For some reason, for my elementary number theory class, they want us do to stuff like writing the greatest common divisor of big numbers as a linear combination of them, or chinese remainder theorem with big numbers. This is a very tedious, long, frustrating and error-prone process.

For example, a question was to find integers $a,b$ such that  $1680a+ 294b =\gcd(1680, 294)$. To apply euclidean algorithm, first you need to divide $1680$ by $294$. The only way i know to do this is by trial and error: $294$ is approximately $300$ so maybe $5$ or $6$ will work. Then i check if it works and continue.

Is there a more systematic faster way to do this? (methods both specific for this and for integer division are interesting).

Comment: Factor the numbers into primes. $1680=2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ and $294=2\cdot 3\cdot 7^2$. These are hardly big numbers.

Comment: @JohnDouma Okay, sure, factoring makes calculation of $\gcd$ quite easy, however they might ask something like writing the $\gcd$ as linear combination of both, in which case can't skip the division. To me they are big numbers to do division by hand. I'll edit the question to not ask how to calculate $\gcd$.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't divide $294$ into $1680$? That's long division.

Comment: I can divide $1680$ by $294$ but it really is a *long* division, it takes me a long time to do it.

Comment: Then you need practice in the basics.

Comment: I mean I could understand 1427476489668697686576667667567567577888653476755865775675643096568855754358547647475765457764676477557646757775587 and division by 294 a bit but 1680 ?

Comment: here is a short bignum library that includes division https://github.com/indy256/codelibrary/blob/master/cpp/numeric/bigint.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional way to do this is by [Long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Example_with_multi-digit_divisor).

In this particular case, though (dividing $1680$ by $294$), the method that you have outlined is about as quick as you can get. Long division requires you to be able to calculate multiples of the divisor ($294$ in this case) up to $10\times$, by which point you'd already have surpassed $1680$.